# How to debug identical strings that do not equal in google app script?

Tags: javascript, string, debugging, google-apps-script

I have 2 identical strings, they appear identical in the debugger (and Logger.log), but when I do `string1 === string2` it returns false. How can I debug this?

One of the string is a google drive file name, and one of the string is from a google sheet cell. I'm guessing there's an invisible character in one of the string but I have no way to see it.

Comment: Check to see if your variables are the same type, "Logger.log(typeof variable);". "===" will only return true if both variables are not just equal in value but type as well.

Comment: `JSON.stringify(string)`

Comment: Curious. What was the issue?

Comment: @TheMaster I don't know, I renamed the file using google drive web interface and the invisible char disappeared before I could debug it so I know it came from file.getName() but nothing else. Very annoying bug it took me hours to pinpoint it on a script that has been working flawlessly for years.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Check `type` of each variable

   ```
   typeof string1 === typeof string2
   ```
2. Check `length` of each string

   ```
   string1.length === string2.length
   ```
3. Loop through each character:

   ```
   [...string1].every((char,i) => char === string2[i] || console.info(`Unequal character at ${i}`))
   ```
4. Check unicode of each character:

   ```
   console.log([...string1].map((char,i) => [char, char.codePointAt(0),string2.codePointAt(i)]))
   ```