# Issue matching argument in google script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am new to scripting, and have been trying to get a script to place a date in an adjacent cell when a checkbox is checked. This is a minor part of the whole script I am trying to get working. I am trying to write a script to build a new sheet from another sheets values, including naming the sheet.

I can get the script to work when I type the sheet name into the if statement, but when I try and use an argument by calling the sheet name and calling string, I can not get them to return a true value.

When I log the sheet name and the string they match. If I copy and paste ether value from the log into the sheet name it will then return true. It will also return true when I type the name of the sheet.

I have tried to change the type using: `toString()` but this has not worked.

I have tried to use the `length` and `typeof` to find the solution, from this page:

[How to debug identical strings that do not equal in google app script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63062562/how-to-debug-identical-strings-that-do-not-equal-in-google-app-script)

But they where the same type and length. I have tried to get the `every` function on this page to work but have been unsuccessful in getting it to run.

I have used it like this:

```
[td].every((char,i) => char === nac[i] || console.info(`Unequal character at ${i}`))
```

and get this error:

```
10:55:03 AM Error   
TypeError: Cannot read property 'every' of undefined
onEdit  @ Time Stamp test day.gs:33
```

Code:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ac = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var as = ss.getActiveSheet().getSheetName();
 
  var d = new Date();

  var month = new Array(12);
  month[0] = "Jan";
  month[1] = "Feb";
  month[2] = "Mar";
  month[3] = "Apl";
  month[4] = "May";
  month[5] = "Jun";
  month[6] = "Jul";
  month[7] = "Aug";
  month[8] = "Sep";
  month[9] = "Oct";
  month[10] = "Nov";
  month[11] = "Dec";
  
  var year = d.getFullYear();
  var date = d.getDate();
  var today = month[d.getMonth()] + " " + date +", " + year
  var td = "Test " + today
  var nac = ac.getSheetName()
  
Logger.log(td)
Logger.log(nac)
Logger.log(nac == td)

if(nac == td) {

  var cell = ac.getActiveCell()
  var col = cell.getColumn()

  if(col == 9 && cell.getValue() == true){

    Logger.log(123456)

    var date = new Date()
    var dateCell = cell.offset(0,1)

    dateCell.setValue(date)

    }//close if
  } // Close if
} // Close function
```

Log

```
11:26:46 PM Notice  Execution started
11:26:47 PM Info    Test Dec 27, 2020
11:26:47 PM Info    Test Dec 27, 2020
11:26:47 PM Info    false
11:26:47 PM Notice  Execution completed
```

Comment: If the linked duplicate doesn't help, [edit] your question to show why it doesn't answer your question.

Comment: You missed the three dots before `td`( the spread operator)

Comment: Thanks @TheMaster, when I use the 3 dots before `td` it will not run at all. `[...td].every((char,i) => char === nac[i] || console.info(`Unequal character at ${i}`))`
log: `11:02:22 AM Error Attempted to execute onEdit, but could not save.`

Comment: Are you using v8 engine?

Comment: I am using the updated google scripts.

Comment: Not sure what's wrong but try in a new script project. Also I've reopened your question-incase anyone else wants to answer.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I tried it in a new project, and tried to use the legacy editor and both will not work with or without the 3 dots.