# Comparing values is returning FALSE even though they are exactly the same - Google App Script

Tags: csv, google-apps-script, google-sheets, string-matching

I do have some CSV files that I imported from Google drive and import them on a Google Sheet using Apps Script. I was able to import the data with 1 issue where the first cell (A1) has quotation marks. I was able to have a workaround on that issue and used `replace(/"/g, "")`. Now, my issue is that whenever I compare that value to exactly the same string value, it always return as false. Other cells (A2) works fine when compared, only this cell has the issue. I already tried using `get.DisplayValue`, applying formula and copy pasting, but none works. I also tried converting both to string (which they already are) but also fails. Here is the code.

```
function importCSV(folder) 
  {
    var files = folder.getFiles();
    while (files.hasNext()) 
    {
      var file = files.next();
      Logger.log('file.getName()',file.getName());
      csvArray = file.getBlob().getDataAsString("UTF-8");
      csvArray = Utilities.parseCsv(csvArray);
      sheet.getRange (1,1,csvArray.length,csvArray[0].length).setValues(csvArray)
      var substring0 = csvArray[0][0].replace(/"/g, "");
      sheet.getRange(1,1).setValue(substring0)    
      var substring1 = sheet.getRange("A1").getValue()
      var substring2 = sheet.getRange("B1").getValue();
      
      

      var compare1 = substring1 == "Live pages";
      var compare2 = substring2 == "Views";
```

compare1 always returns as FALSE for some reason even though they are exactly the same. Any advice?

[Variables also matched but compare1 still FALSE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmmpk.png)

Comment: Check for extra spaces between before and after the words... You can also check that by checking the length of the string. `substring1.length` should match `"Live pages".length`

Comment: If the linked question's answer don't satisfy you, [edit] your question with debug data as suggested in the answer.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me on the right direction. I've been working on this for hours. Yes, they are indeed has different lengths, subtring1 seems to have 1 additional length. However, when I try to add space before and after the words, the comparison is still failing. Any ideas how to remove those extra hidden characters? Thanks again!

Comment: @jatacs Try https://stackoverflow.com/a/63062700/

Comment: Thanks for the help! What I did to resolve the issue was to add ````.trim()```` after the get.Values. Here's what solved the issue.

````var substring1 = sheet.getRange("A1").getValue().trim();````