# Google Scripts editor || not working in IF Statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Can anyone please tell me why the || in if statement is not working. If I take out the || it will produce the desired results of logging the cell number if its not equal.

```
   function ReformatSheet() {
    
      var GoFlowWHInv = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1pXWj_UOTVy_mFB5gRUPbDfzNJcAK09Z-mDyXPKUJaLE");
      var Data = GoFlowWHInv.getDataRange()
      var Values = GoFlowWHInv.getDataRange().getValues()
    
      Values[i][4]
    
      for (var i = 0; i < Values.length; i++) {
    
        if(Values[i][4] !== "Item Type" || Values[i][4] !== "Standard Product") {
    
          Logger.log(Values[i][4]);
    
        }
      }
```

Here is the log that I ran both before the for loop and in the for loop.

It should log the first but not the second if it has Item Type or Standard Product therefore I should only see back to back Standard Products in the log.

```
12:26:12 PM Notice  Execution started
12:26:13 PM Info    Item Type
12:26:13 PM Info    Item Type
12:26:13 PM Info    Kit Product
12:26:13 PM Info    Kit Product
12:26:13 PM Info    Standard Product
12:26:13 PM Info    Standard Product
12:26:13 PM Info    Kit Product
```

Comment: Why don't you `console.log(Values[i][4])` before the `if` statement to see why it is not working?

Comment: I did using Logger.log() as that is how you console log in script editor.  however, it shows as the text is correct. In addition I have changed to just value with != and I have tried trimming the text before hand incase there was empty space before or after text.

Comment: Try these ways of debugging your code: [How to debug identical strings that do not equal in google app script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63062562/how-to-debug-identical-strings-that-do-not-equal-in-google-app-script)

Comment: I don't believe it has to do with type of string or character count. If I run the same if statement with only one condition it matches. It is acting as though once I put the or statement in it is not reading the condition correctly.

Comment: `It should log the first but not the second if it has Item Type or Standard Product` Could you explain it in different words? What's the expected output and why?

Comment: Your if statement will always return a "true" value. In any case, one of the two conditions inside "if" will always be true. And as it is 'or', the output will always be true.

Comment: @ThomasStevens explain in **plain** english what you want to achieve. Also you kinda showed to us that you expect but you didn't show the input itself.

Comment: Sorry for the mass confusion somehow Tom Sharpe understood but here it goes again. 

I had a column in google sheets or an array of values. I needed too loop through values and capture the rows with either item type or standard product text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using && not ||. In this line

```
if(Values[i][4] !== "Item Type" && Values[i][4] !== "Standard Product")
```

it will always call the logger because even if the cell contains Item Type or Standard Product, the other part of the whole expression will be true and it will print to the logger.

For example, if the cell contains Item Type

`Values[i][4] !== "Item Type"` evaluates to false

but

`Values[i][4] !== "Standard Product"` evaluates to true

false || true evaluates to true so the whole if statement succeeds.

So you should use this instead:

```
if(Values[i][4] !== "Item Type" && Values[i][4] !== "Standard Product")
```

You could also invert the logic and use ||

```
if(!(Values[i][4] === "Item Type" || Values[i][4] === "Standard Product"))
```

Comment: I understand what you are saying. I guess I am confused because is the meaning of || not this or that? && Would evaluate both statements.Therefore, both instances would give me a wrong log. Would I not need a If else statement in this case.

Comment: Nevermind I understand what you are saying now.