# String Equality in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, string, google-apps-script, equality

I'm trying to compare a name retrieved from a JSON object, with a name as it exists on a google Sheet. Try as I might, I can't get a comparison that yields a positive.
I've tried:

`IndexOf`

`localeCompare`

`==`

`===`

I've tried
`key===value`
`String(key)===String(value)` and
`String(key).valueof()=String(value).valueof`.
I've also tried calling `trim()` on everything to make sure there are no leading/trailing white spaces (there aren't, as confirmed with a `length()` comparison.

As you can see from the screen shot, the values of `key` and `value` are exactly the same.
Any pointers would be gratefully received. This has held up my project for days!

[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4UDL.jpg)

Comment: In your showing image, shouldn't `String(key).valueof` be `String(key).valueof()`?

Comment: String(key).valueof()=String(value).valueof, is there should be () at the end of valueOf ? On your screenshot there isn't either.  I'm not sure if that's the cause of the error, if you can , please post the error message.  That might be helpful

Comment: Thanks - I actually spotted that and fixed it but pasted the wrong imgur link. Here's the updated link https://imgur.com/a/dwlVojM. There's no error message, I just don't ever get a match. The equality test always fails.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63062562/how-to-debug-identical-strings-that-do-not-equal-in-google-app-script/63062700#63062700) answer your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Description**

This is not a solution but it might help find the problem.  Perhaps the characters in one or the other is not what you think.  Visually they compare, but what if one has a tab instead of a space.  Try this, list the character codes for each and see if any character has a different value.

I've added another option that eliminates the for loop thanks to @TheMaster

**Script (Option 1)**

```
function test() {
  try {
    let text = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Test").getRange("A1").getValue();
    console.log(text);
    let code = [];
    for( let i=0; i<text.length; i++ ) {
      code.push(text.charCodeAt(i))
    }
    console.log(code.join());
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

**Script (Option 2)**

```
function test() {
  try {
    let text = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Test").getRange("A1").getValue();
    console.log(text);
    let code = [];
    [...text].forEach( char => code.push(char.charCodeAt(0)) );
    console.log(code.join());
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

**Execution log**

```
7:57:53 AM  Notice  Execution started
7:57:56 AM  Info    Archie White
7:57:56 AM  Info    65,114,99,104,105,101,32,87,104,105,116,101
7:57:54 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```

Comment: This is a good idea thanks. I ran this for both and it turns out that the space in the name from the list of names on the google sheet is a different character code to that of the name from the JSON object. Interesting thing is, I'm constructing the name from the JSON object by ``first_name + " " + last_name`` (see imgur.com/a/dwlVojM ). So a space used in GAS code is not equal to a space defined on a Gsheet! The character codes are 160 and 32. I'm now trying to find what their definitions are....

Answer (score 0):

#### Compare

```
function compare() {
  const json = '{"values":[["good","bad","ugly"]]}';
  const obj = JSON.parse(json);
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const [hA,...vs] = sh.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  let matches = [];
  vs.forEach((r,i) => {
    r.forEach((c,j) => {
      let idx = obj.values[0].indexOf(c);
      if(~idx) {
        matches.push({row:i+1,col:j+1,index: idx});
      }
    })
  })
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(matches))
 }

Execution log
9:31:50 AM  Notice  Execution started
9:31:52 AM  Info    [{"row":1,"col":1,"index":0},{"row":2,"col":1,"index":1},{"row":3,"col":1,"index":2}]
9:31:51 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```

Sheet1:

| COL1 |
| --- |
| good |
| bad |
| ugly |

Comment: Hi -- many thanks for your code - I went with the answer above as it was posted first